# Screen flicker between screens transition in libgdx

Tags: android, libgdx

All my screens are working as intended except there is a flicker when one screen calls another. An example would be calling StoreScreen from my MainScreen, but this happens across all screens.

Here is my mainscreen show, render and the button which calls the other screen.

```
 public StoreScreen(TiltorGame tiltorGame) {
    game = tiltorGame;
    w = 800;
    h = 480;
    shapeDebugger = new ShapeRenderer();
}
@Override
    public void show() {
        camera = new OrthographicCamera();
        camera.setToOrtho(false, w, h);
        FitViewport viewp = new FitViewport(w, h, camera); // change this to
                                                            // your needed
                                                            // viewport
        stage = new Stage(viewp); // also pass the singelton batch here. Try
                                    // just to use onee batch to have a good
                                    // performance.
        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);
        font = new BitmapFont();
        font.setColor(0.5f, 0.4f, 0, 1); // Brown is an underated Colour
        shapeDebugger = new ShapeRenderer();
        table1 = new Table();
        table2 = new Table();
        table3 = new Table();

        drawTable1();
    }
```

//

```
@Override
public void render(float delta) {
// Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
drawLines();

stage.getBatch().begin();
Assets.backgroundSprite.draw(stage.getBatch());

table1.setBounds(0, 0, w / 3, h);
table2.setBounds(table1.getWidth(), 0, w / 3, h);
table3.setBounds(table1.getWidth() * 2, 0, w / 3, h);
stage.addActor(table1);
stage.addActor(table2);
stage.addActor(table3);

font.draw(stage.getBatch(), "Coins: " + String.valueOf(Data.coins),
        400, 35);
font.draw(stage.getBatch(),
        "FPS: " + String.valueOf(Gdx.graphics.getFramesPerSecond()),
        700, 450);
stage.getBatch().end();

stage.act(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime());
stage.getBatch().setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
stage.draw();
}
```

//

```
TextButton buttonStore = new TextButton("Store", skin, "default");

buttonStore.setWidth(400f);
buttonStore.setHeight(75f);
buttonStore.addListener(new ClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y) {
        game.setScreen(new StoreScreen(game));
    }
});

table1.add(buttonStore);
table1.row();
```

Also here is the StoreScreen show

```
@Override
public void show() {
camera = new OrthographicCamera();
camera.setToOrtho(false, w, h);
FitViewport viewp = new FitViewport(w, h, camera); // change this to
                                                    // your needed
                                                    // viewport
stage = new Stage(viewp); // also pass the singelton batch here. Try
                            // just to use onee batch to have a good
                            // performance.
Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);
font = new BitmapFont();
font.setColor(0.5f, 0.4f, 0, 1); // Brown is an underated Colour
table1 = new Table();
drawButtons();
}
```

Comment: I think it's because you're creating a new camera and stage each time in the show() function rather than initialize these variables in the constructor call. The bitmap font is certainly a native resource that must be explicitly dispose()'d so I'm certain that there is a better approach to this.

Comment: also don't `stage.addActor(table1);` inside the render method. You don't need to add the table to your stage in each frame.